# Displaying loading spinner in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

The loading spinner will not show, even though the page takes about 4 seconds to render and be displayed. What I did: At button click I call a method and at the beginning of the method I call this: function taskStat(){ $.mobile.loading('show'); $.mobile.changePage("#taskStatistics",{transition: "none"}); ..... other methods are then called including db calls (no ajax calls)

in the last method I call this at the end: $.mobile.loading('hide');

From the mainpage to the taskStatistics page the local db calls and html items being dynamically created and displayed take about 4 to 5 seconds during which the page freezes on the mainpage and then goes to the stats page. Why wouldn't the loader show? Any suggested workarounds? Thank you

Part of the code:

```
    function taskStat(){
        $.mobile.loading('show',{theme:'d',textonly:false,html:""});
        $.mobile.changePage("#taskStatistics",{transition: "none"});
        statQueries= new Array();
        offsetInitial=0;
        db.transaction(taskStatsBefore, errorCB);
    } 

    function taskStatsBefore(tx){
        var query="select COUNT(*) AS MYCOUNT1 from TASKS_GVT";
        tx.executeSql(query,[],taskStatsBeforeCb,errorCB);
    }
```

...several other methods where I take the db results and create html elements for the next page dynamically
last method ends with this: $.mobile.loading('hide');

Comment: Are you seeing any error in the console?

Comment: No Raymond no errors, even tried a try and catch but no error is caught. @RaymondCamden I tried another approach, to display an image in the current page (mainpage) on button click and then when the page finishes rendering I go to the next page and call changepage but again it doesnt display.

Comment: Is it online so we can see?

Comment: Mm no its a phonegap/cordova project @RaymondCamden I tried keeping the image i display in the mainpage and not removing it. I see it when I go back to the page. So the problem is that when I'm calling the db calls and rendering the html in the other page nothing is being changed and the app freezes (whats weird though is that im displaying the image before i start any call to render the next page!), do you suggest any workarounds?

Comment: So wait - you have 2 issues then? The loading image not showing and an apparent freeze? I'd suggest a second SO question so as to not confuse this one. Also - what happens if tastStat *only* has one line, the mobile.loading one?

Comment: Mm no I dont have 2 issues, by "the app freezes" i mean its loading the next page so its not responding to any other change in the html i make to the current page. @RaymondCamden Also if it has only that one line it will display the image/show the loader.

Comment: Ok, so can you show the entire method?

Comment: I believe, stress believe, it is a bad idea to call the changePage there as when it finishes it may dismiss the loading widget automatically. If you remove JUST that, do things work ok?

Comment: I did previously try calling the change page at the end (last method), same result though @RaymondCamden

Comment: Weird - and if you remove the rest, it DOES work, right?

Comment: Yes if I remove the db calls and the rest it does work. I believe its taking my command at the end for some reason, a command im calling at the beginning of the method! I believe that since I tried not removing the image at the end and when i go back to the page i see it displayed. @RaymondCamden

Comment: Does it work if you keep everything but the db call?

Comment: Mm the rest is all related to the db calls so it wont make a difference if I have only the first method or the rest without the db calls.. @RaymondCamden

Comment: I'm just trying to narrow it down. You have 4 lines after the loading widget, right? And you said if ALL are gone, it works. Can you try and see if one line in particular is the issue? Like comment out the 4 and bring back one at a time.

Comment: Thank you @RaymondCamden for trying to help really! I did however develop a solution very similar to the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding setTimeout with a timeout of 0 or 100ms.
Without timeout, the browser waits untill the task is finished before it refreshes the UI.

```
function taskStat(){
    $.mobile.loading('show',{theme:'d',textonly:false,html:""});
    $.mobile.changePage("#taskStatistics",{transition: "none"});
    setTimeout(function(){
        statQueries= new Array();
        offsetInitial=0;
        db.transaction(taskStatsBefore, errorCB);
    },0);
} 

function taskStatsBefore(tx){
    var query="select COUNT(*) AS MYCOUNT1 from TASKS_GVT";
    tx.executeSql(query,[],taskStatsBeforeCb,errorCB);
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you! I have done something similar. I left the page transition till the end (last method) then called this  window.setTimeout(function(){$.mobile.loading('hide');$.mobile.changePage("#taskStatistics",{transition: "none"});},100);
same concept right? Any disadvantages you see in my method?

Comment: I'm not an expert of how browsers handle parallel tasks launched with setTimeOut, so I'm not sure wich is best. I did the way I did because I'm more used to start time consuming tasks in new threads and leave the rendering thread just render (of course here as everything is done in the same thread, that doesn't really apply)